# how to draw text to bitmap in python?

Tags: python, bmp

I want to create text to bitmap. the text is considered long string text.

so please tell me how to create a bitmap from a text.

I tried this :

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont
img = Image.new('L', (500, 500), color=0)
img_w, img_h = img.size
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 20)
mask = font.getmask('some text related location that is going to write here.'
                    'this is watermark text', mode='L')
mask_w, mask_h = mask.size
print(mask_w,mask_h)
print(type(mask))
d = Image.core.draw(img.im, 0)
# d = d.rotate(40)
d.draw_bitmap(((img_w - mask_w)/2, (img_h - mask_h)/2), mask, 255)
img = img.rotate(40)
img.show()
img.save('op.jpg')
```

But text is cut from both side.
here is what i get. [image]

Comment: Have you tried printing your image before rotating it? `img = img.rotate(40)` statement might be the reason behind this.

Comment: yes..ofcourse i tried.. before rotating text is cutting same way..

Comment: https://haptik.ai/tech/putting-text-on-images-using-python%E2%80%8A-%E2%80%8Apart2/ try this link

Answer (score 4):

The text is cut from both sides because it was already cut by the horizontal boundary of the image before you rotate it. You should create an image with a width large enough to accommodate the entire text before you rotate it. That is to say, you should create an `Image` object with a width of `mask_w` after you obtain it.

Comment: This is not a solution for me.. If the text length is very long so every time i have to create large width. Even i create large width and text length is more then width so it is not possible to create large width

Comment: If you want a long string in your output, you need a large width. Why would you expect otherwise?

Comment: Specifically, you should create an `Image` object with a width of `mask_w` after you obtain it.